# Oracle: Nested cursors need to compare all rows to all other rows

Tags: oracle, cursor

In the below example, t1 has millions of rows. I need to compare each row in t1 to each other row in t1 and then if I find a match insert a row into t2. With a simple nested cursor option I have below, it takes way too long to process data. id is a unique sequential number, so all rows are not processed I only check for matches when id1 < id2. I know this is like half a Cartesian product - not sure how else to handle it. Any thoughts?

```
cursor c1 is select id,x,y,z from t1;
cursor c2 is select id,x,y,z from t1;
BEGIN
open c1;
loop
    fetch c1 into v1_x, v1_y, v1_z;
    open c2;  
    loop
        fetch c2 into v2_x, v2_y, v2_z;
        if  v1_id < v2_id then
            if v1_x = v2_x then
                if v1_y = v2_y then
                    if v1_z = v2_z then
                        insert into t2 (id1, id2) values (v_id1, v_id2);
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        exit when c2%notfound;
    end loop;
    close c2;
    exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;
close c1;
END;
```

Thanks.

Gary

Answer (score 1):

I'd try without PL/SQL. Loop is row-by-row processing, which is (for large data sets) slow-by-slow. Nested loops for large data sets? Suicide.

How about this?

```
merge into t2 c
  using (select a.id id1, a.x x1, a.y y1, a.z z1,
                b.id id2, b.x x2, b.y y2, b.z z2
         from t1 a join t2 b on b.id < a.id
                            and b.x = a.x
                            and b.y = a.y
                            and b.z = a.z
        ) x
  on (1 = 1)
  when not matched then insert (id1, id2)
    values (x.id1, x.id2);
```

---

Example based on Scott's sample schema, its `EMP` table. I'll store rows where `DEPTNO` and `JOB` match. My target table contains some more columns that yours, just to make it easier to follow.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, deptno, job from emp
  2  order by deptno, job, empno;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7934 MILLER             10 CLERK        -- no matches for DEPTNO = 10
      7782 CLARK              10 MANAGER
      7839 KING               10 PRESIDENT

      7788 SCOTT              20 ANALYST      -- in DEPTNO 20 Scott and Ford are analysts,
      7902 FORD               20 ANALYST      
      7369 SMITH              20 CLERK        -- while Smith and Adams are clerks
      7876 ADAMS              20 CLERK        -- so they should be inserted into T2
      7566 JONES              20 MANAGER

      7900 JAMES              30 CLERK
      7698 BLAKE              30 MANAGER
      7499 ALLEN              30 SALESMAN     -- Allen matches Ward, Martin and Turner ...
      7521 WARD               30 SALESMAN     -- as they are all salesmen. Etc.
      7654 MARTIN             30 SALESMAN
      7844 TURNER             30 SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

My target table:

```
SQL> create table t2
  2  (id1     number,               -- you have only ID1 and ...
  3   id2     number,               -- ... ID2
  4   ename1  varchar2(10),
  5   ename2  varchar2(10),
  6   deptno1 number,
  7   deptno2 number,
  8   job1    varchar2(10),
  9   job2    varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into t2 c
  2    using (select a.empno id1, a.ename ename1, a.deptno deptno1, a.job job1,
  3                  b.empno id2, b.ename ename2, b.deptno deptno2, b.job job2
  4           from emp a join emp b on b.empno  < a.empno
  5                                and b.deptno = a.deptno
  6                                and b.job    = a.job
  7          ) x
  8    on (1 = 1)
  9    when not matched then insert (id1, id2, ename1, ename2, deptno1, deptno2, job1, job2)
 10      values (x.id1, x.id2, x.ename1, x.ename2, x.deptno1, x.deptno2, x.job1, x.job2);

8 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from t2 order by ename1, ename2;

       ID1        ID2 ENAME1     ENAME2        DEPTNO1    DEPTNO2 JOB1       JOB2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7876       7369 ADAMS      SMITH              20         20 CLERK      CLERK     -- Adams and Smith
      7902       7788 FORD       SCOTT              20         20 ANALYST    ANALYST   -- Scott and Ford
      7654       7499 MARTIN     ALLEN              30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN  -- Allen and Martin
      7654       7521 MARTIN     WARD               30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN
      7844       7499 TURNER     ALLEN              30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN  -- Allen and Turner
      7844       7654 TURNER     MARTIN             30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN
      7844       7521 TURNER     WARD               30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN
      7521       7499 WARD       ALLEN              30         30 SALESMAN   SALESMAN  -- Allen and Ward

8 rows selected.
```

---

Looks OK to me, works fast on my 14-rows-sample-table. Now, give it a try on your multimillion table.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. Though I am not sure I understand how there are 2 different "b" tables. "b" seems to represent both t1 and t2 unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: You're welcome. And you're right, I should've paid more attention to aliases. Fixed now. Wouldn't do anything "wrong" to the final result, though, but yes - queries should be written so that there's no doubt of what is what. I apologize.

Comment: You have on b.empno  < a.empno, but for my query I flipped it accidentally and had  a.empno  < b.empno and no rows were found. Why would that be? Why does it matter which one is compared?

Comment: It is used so that you wouldn't compare the same row with itself. It works OK in my example - you'll have to find your own  condition(s) to make it work, based on data stored in your tables.

Comment: This worked great for some small cases but once I opened it up for the whole table it was taking way too long. My query is actually somewhat more complex than the basic way I posted above. Any hints on what indexes to create here? Single indexes? Composite? I've never written a query this intensive.

Comment: Indexes? Most probably on all columns involved in JOIN.